# How can i tell my Program to "re-do" diffrent Actions (chosen by User-Input) after it is done, till the do-while Requirement is set?

Tags: c#, input, console, readline

Im just a Beginner in C# and im working on a Console Application, I want the Program to be able to read the Input of the User and execute the Orders until he has 0 HP. Its basicly gonna be "Fighting-Game".

My Problem now, I can only ask for the User Input once(and it will only execute the Input that the Program once got). I want to add additional Fighting Options aswell, but for now im stuck here.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int playerHealth = 100;
        int playerDamageSword = 10;
        int playerDamageFire = 10;
        int playerHeal = 20;

        int enemyHealth = 100;


        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Enter your Character Name!");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Okay! " + name + " You have encountered an Enemy! Which Action do you choose?\n1.Sword-Attack\n2.Fire-Attack\n3.Heal\n8.Flee\n9.Quit\n" );
        string Input = Console.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            if (Input == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You hit your Opponment for 10 Damage!");
                enemyHealth = enemyHealth - 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Your Opponment hit you back for 10 Damage!");
                playerHealth = playerHealth - 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Your Current Hp: " + playerHealth);
                Console.WriteLine("Opponment Current HP: " + enemyHealth);

            }

            else if (Input == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You healed yourself for 20 HP");
                playerHealth = playerHealth + 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Your Current Hp: " + playerHealth);
                Console.WriteLine("Opponment Current HP: " + enemyHealth);


            }
        } while (playerHealth > 0);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just move `string Input = Console.ReadLine();` to the top of the `do{}while();` and add your extra output where needed

Comment: Oh my...Thank You :/ It's really difficult to get into programing as complete Noob

Comment: We've all been there! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, you need to move the input read into your loop like so:

```
    string Input;

    do
    {
        Input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Input == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You hit your Opponment for 10 Damage!");
            enemyHealth = enemyHealth - 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Opponment hit you back for 10 Damage!");
            playerHealth = playerHealth - 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Current Hp: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Opponment Current HP: " + enemyHealth);

        }

        else if (Input == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You healed yourself for 20 HP");
            playerHealth = playerHealth + 20;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Current Hp: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Opponment Current HP: " + enemyHealth);


        }
    } while (playerHealth > 0);
```

What this will do:

1. Begin loop
2. Get user input and store it into the `Input` string
3. Check `if (Input == "1")` or the `else if (Input == "2")` condition
4. Check `(playerHealth > 0)` and then move back to the top of the loop
   or exit the loop

Comment: Thank You ! Will mark it as answered, once its possible!